# ECONNRESET, MongoNetworkError in node.js web application

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb, express

I am currently developing a website using Node.js, Express, and MongoDB (MLAB). My code would be very long if I put it here. So when I try to get to my index

```
app.get("/alumniport", (req, res) => {
  alumni.find((err, theAlumni) => {
    if (err) {
      res.redirect("/");
    } else {
    res.render("alumniport", { alumni: theAlumni });
    }
  });
});
```

I have to wait for a few seconds before this error pops up. I have searched what it is and have no clue what it is

```
{ Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TCP.onread (net.js:622:25)
  name: 'MongoNetworkError',
  errorLabels: [ 'TransientTransactionError' ],
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }
```

the tricky part is that, when I access the internet through my university wifi, the MLAB refuses to connect, but it connects when I use public internet. Is there something wrong in my computer's configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like problem with your mlab connection I think. Try to connect like this:

```js
const MONGO_URL = 'mongodb://<dbuser>:<dbpassword>@ds111370.mlab.com:11370/dbname'
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect(MONGO_URL, { useNewUrlParser: true }).then(
  () => {console.log('Database is connected') },
  err => { console.log('Can not connect to the database'+ err)}
);
```

Comment: thanks for the response. I get the database connected message in my console but still it doesn't work

Comment: Its very uncommon bug. Well I found this link: 
https://support.glitch.com/t/cant-connect-to-mongodb-cluster-discord-js-mongoose-econreset/6371/12
Check last posts. Maybe it  help you :D

Comment: i can access it in different wifi network, but not with this one. do u know how different wifi affects my connection?

Comment: umm, how can I get all the shards from my mongodb? Im using MLAB so I cant access mongodb through my console